# How to change the histogram borderline thickness in ggplot geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(bins=15, colour='red')
```

Which produce this:

[image]

As stated there, how can I change the  thickness of the enclosing line of the histogram?

Comment: Best practice is to remove border line

Comment: but you can use `size=3`

Answer (score 23):

Just use `size` argument

```
geom_histogram(bins=15, colour='red',size=2)
```

Answer (score 8):

Easy enough :)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(bins=15, colour='red',size=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to program in point space, I used the following function:

```
MyPoints <- function(desired_points){
  return (unit(desired_points*.5*(1/1.07), "point"))
}

geom_histogram(size=MyPoints(1))
```